# Best way to grant constraint respect in my database (trigger or procedure)

Tags: database-design, plsql, relational-database

I am implementing a database in oracle sql. In this phase, i am always asking myself if, for some constraints, it is better to use a trigger or a stored procedure. Until now i followed this principle: "I use a stored procedure only and only if i can't implement it with a trigger". For example, i use stored procedures instead of triggers of type **AFTER INSERT ON** that requires the lecture of the table in which i am inserting (this would cause an error). But if i think to the user of my database, i find it hard to encase the logic of a constraint into a stored procedure; suppose that i have a table A and a constraint B, implemented with a stored procedure, that regulates inserting on this table. What prevents user from using a **INSERT INTO A** statement, ignoring all the constraint checking phase of the procedure? I just find triggers more "secure" than procedures, but i recognize that procedures are more powerful and less problematics than triggers. Someone can help me with this problem?

Comment: Any response is an opinion, all probably valid under a given set of circumstances. You'll find that a 1-size fits all strategy often doesn't work well. My normal choice 1: Built in constraint and don't overlook check constraints. 2: Trigger for simple rules not available with built in constraints. Simple being those the require access to only to Old an New records of the firing table. 4. Application called stored procedures. 5. Application code. As for as users getting around those constraints see below.

Comment: What kind of constraint do you need? That is, are you sure you can't use check constraints, foreign keys, … ? Can you post an example of the constraints you need?

Answer (score 1):

If you believe it's really necessary to prevent user inserting/updating but not getting the rules correct you can accomplish this by NOT giving access to the table. You do this by:

1. Create a view of the table. Can be just "select * from table"
2. Create an Instead of trigger on the view.
3. Give Users appropriate access to the view, but NOT the table.

Any DML against the view will channel through the Instead of trigger to enforce the constraint. Eaxmple:

```
--  table and view
create table mytable (
    id        varchar2(32 byte)
  , column1   varchar2(10 byte)
  , column2   varchar2(10 byte)
  , column3   varchar2(1 byte)
) ;
alter table mytable add ( constraint mytable_pk primary key (id));
create or replace view myview as select * from mytable;

 -- at this pont it's just an updatable view
 insert into myview (id, column1, column2, column3)
  values ('2980282-3085A', 'zzzz','tr','x');
select * from mytable;

-- Now enforce a rule on table/view that the user cannot get around
-- Let's enforce the following:
--   If column3 contains upper case letter then any letter in id must also be upper case
--   if column3 caltains lower case letter then any letter in id must also be lower case
--   if column3 contains a non-letter then no restriction on letters in id.
create or replace trigger myview_instead_insert  
instead of insert or update on myview
for each row
begin 
    dbms_output.put_line(' Executing Instead of trigger: Apply Necessary constrinait in here');

    if INSERTING 
    then
        insert into mytable(id, column1, column2, column3)
             select case when :new.column3 between 'A' and 'Z' then upper(:new.id)
                         when :new.column3 between 'a' and 'z' then lower(:new.id)
                         else :new.id
                    end
                 , :new.column1 
                 , :new.column2
                 , :new.column3
          from dual;
    else
       update mytable
         set id = case when :new.column3 between 'A' and 'Z' then upper(:new.id)
                       when :new.column3 between 'a' and 'z' then lower(:new.id)
                       else :new.id
                  end
           , column1 = :new.column1
           , column2 = :new.column2 
           , column3 = :new.column3
      where id = :old.id;
    end if;                    
end myview_instead_insert ;  


-- test insert
insert into myview (id, column1, column2, column3)
with test as 
     (select 'abc_3849' id, '234' column1, 'CVx' column2, 'U' column3 from dual union all 
      select 'Abc_3849AA' , '234',         'CVx',         'l'         from dual union all
      select 'aBc_3849Al' , '234',         'CVx',         '0'         from dual
    )
select id, column1,column2,column3 
  from test;

 select * from mytable;

 -- test update
 update myview 
   set column3 = 'U'
 where column3 = '0';
```

Disclaimer: I make no contention that this is the best method, only it is a demonstration.